# wxpython: destroy cancelled ProgressDialog

Tags: wxpython

I can't get a wx.ProgressDialog to close.  If it expires; everything is fine.  Clicking cancel or skip will break out of the dialog, but the window stays frozen forever on the screen (control flow returns).

```
import wx
def Progress(parent=None, message="", title="", maximum=3000):
  dlg = wx.GenericProgressDialog(title, message, maximum,style=wx.PD_AUTO_HIDE|wx.PD_APP_MODAL|wx.PD_CAN_SKIP|wx.PD_CAN_ABORT)
  keepGoing = True
  skip = False
  count = 0

  while keepGoing and (not skip) and count < maximum:
      count += 1
      wx.MilliSleep(1)
      wx.Yield()
      (keepGoing, skip_bogus) = dlg.Update(count)
      skip = dlg.WasSkipped()  #NOTE:  skip_bogus doesn't ever seem to update; even when skip button is clicked

  dlg.Destroy()
  wx.Yield()

  if not keepGoing:
      return "cancel"
  elif skip:
      return "skip" 
  else:
      return None

app = wx.App()
app.MainLoop()

Progress(None, "message", "title")
```

wxpython v3.0.2
python v2.7.10

Answer (score 1):

It may be somewhat platform dependent, but calling your `Progress` function after the `MainLoop` returns is a red flag for me. Top-level windows are not destroyed when their `Destroy` method is called, instead they are added to a pending delete queue which is processed later in the event loop.

Try putting the call to `Process` before the `MainLoop` call, and remove the call to `wx.Yield` after the `Destroy`.  That works for me on OSX and Phoenix.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical example of a [LongRunningTask](https://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks): Your `while` loop will eat up all time not used for event handling. When events start to pile up, the GUI gets unresponsive and wxPython is no longer able to process any events in time (or handle calls to `wx.Yield()`, for that matter).

The solution for that problem is to put blocking events/long runnings tasks in a separate thread and call back into the GUI thread-safe by using e. g. `wx.CallAfter` when the work is done.

Study the last example in the link given above, `Easiest Example *ever* :)` to get an idea how to do that.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem.  AFTER the loop exits the dialog doesn't get destroyed.  CPU usage during the loop is irrelevant.

Comment: Admittedly your example works for me with the **exact same** configuration as yours (Python things 32 bit, Win7 64 bit) without the slightest change. Even changes as proposed by @RobinDunn are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Robin and nepix32's answers are valuable advice. Also, why not use `wx.Timer` to continuously update the dialog? Something like:

```
class Progress:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dlg = wx.GenericProgressDialog(whatever)
        self.count = 0

    def Start(self):
        self._update()
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self.dlg)
        self.dlg.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self._update, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(1) # 1ms interval

    def _update(self, evt=None):
        self.count += 1
        if self.count == self.dlg.GetRange():
            self._stop()
        else:
            self.dlg.Update(self.count)
            if self.dlg.WasSkipped() or self.dlg.WasCancelled():
                self._stop()

    def _stop(self):
        self.timer.Stop()
        self.dlg.Close()
        wx.GetApp().ExitMainLoop()
```

**The answer to your question - how to close the dialog - is `wx.GetApp().ExitMainLoop()`.**